# How to resize Box , Open Layers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am able to draw **box** and I can also **move/drag** box correctly.
But, how can I resize the box?

**what exactly i need** :

OpenLayers 2 Example,

https://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/openlayers/bbox-selector.view.html

**Here is my code**:

```
  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  var source = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});

  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [-11000000, 4600000],
      zoom: 4
    })
  });


var geometryFunction = ol.interaction.Draw.createBox();
box = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: source,
  type: 'Circle',
  geometryFunction: geometryFunction
});

box.on('drawend', function (e) {
  var bounds = e.feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
  console.log(bounds);
});

map.addInteraction(box);
```

**Code for select and drag/move box:**

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();

var translate = new ol.interaction.Translate({
  features: select.getFeatures()
});

translate.on('translateend', function (e) {
  var bounds = e.features.getArray()[0].getGeometry().getExtent()
  console.log(bounds);
});

map.addInteraction(select);
map.addInteraction(translate);
```

Comment: You need to change the geometry of the box to "resize it".

Comment: @Adriani6 can you please elaborate?

Comment: See my answer for elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaboration to my comment:

You need to update/change the geometry of the "box" (polygon I suppose) to make it appear "resized", at the end of any operation that shows something on the map it uses extents that tell OL where to place things (essentially).

I have made a little example demonstrating how to use the `.scale` method on the `Geometry` object of a feature.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VdLwQb?&editors=1010)

Explanation:

```
draw.on("drawend", function(e){
  var iterations = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(iterations == 10){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    iterations++;

    var feature = e.feature;

    var coords = feature.getGeometry();

    coords.scale(0.9, 0.9);

  }, 300)
```

This is the code I use to scale the drawn polygon when the polygon has been drawn on the map. I always scale it by 0.9 (that makes it smaller (Basic scale factoring)).

- 1 = The same size
- 0.* = Smaller
- 1.* = Bigger

You need to use similar logic to this above to resize your polygons. You need feature object, then extract the Geometry object, and use the `.scale` method.

The `scale(sx, yx)` method arguments are as follows:

- sx = The scaling factor in the x-direction.
- yx = The scaling factor in the y-direction (defaults to sx).

For more info [Geometry Class in the OL docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Geometry.html)